# redirect www to non www url using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this code but in this code it's redirect non www to www but i want www to non www.

Please check my script and then tell me how to do this Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
if ( document.domain.substring(0,4) != 'www.' ) {
window.location = document.URL.replace("//","//www."); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Use server side redirection with correct status code 301 or 307.

Comment: @VadimB do you know how to do this ??

Comment: You need to respond to www request with 301 status code and add header "Location=non-ww-url"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do somthing like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("www") == 0) {
    window.location = window.location.href.replace("www.","");
}
</script>
```